# Data corruption in stm32l in c

Tags: c, data-structures, embedded

I am finding some data corruption in the variable u32baudrate, when passed from main to httpinit(). But other variables txsize and flowcontrol are coming out right.

```
typedef struct _test
{
  ...
  uint8_t txsize[5];
  uint32_t u32baudrate;
  uint8_t flowcontrol;
  ...
}test;
```

from main.c

```
test gtest;
gtest.u32baudrate=921600;
printf("baud: %d",gtest.u32baudrate);        //921600: this is coming out right

httpinit(&gtest);
```

in http.c

```
httpinit(test * gtest)
{
  printf("baud: %d",gtest->u32baudrate);     //268435456: this is coming out wrong
}
```

Comment: Those dismissing the *packed* observation might want to rethink in light of an additional clue - the correct value 921600 = 0x000E10000 while the erroneous value 268435456=0x10000000, which looks a lot like an access offset error.  I suspect this processor cannot do unaligned loads, perhaps there's a problem with the toolchain or library configuration not uniformly compensating for that everywhere, while specifying packed forces it to do the access piecewise.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem, it was packing, fixed it by doing this-->

```
typedef PACKED struct _test
{
  ...
  uint8_t txsize[5];
  uint32_t u32baudrate;
  uint8_t flowcontrol;
  ...
}test;
```

Comment: I doubt it.  More likely you have simply changed the nature of the bug by moving the data - something else is now likely being corrupted, expect problems to reoccur in non-deterministic ways when you modify your code.

Comment: @Clifford yes this didn't work, though it hide the corrupted u32Baudrate, but my code is still being corrupted in eeprom, I am using stm32l151rct6a, and iar compiler (I don't have a debugger :(), if you want more information i can give you, can you tell me how to track this bug?

Comment: @Ishmeet are you getting correct values of each element before u32baudrate ?Check for each element and see where exactly corruption started.

Comment: Fixed: In the parse section of Http, where I update the packet for HTTP GET,

`HTTP_DEBUG_MSG("u32BaudRate = %d\n\r",test.u32BaudRate);
   f_memset(temp_buf, 0x00, 1024);
   result=pdest-read_buf;
   f_memcpy(temp_buf, (read_buf+result+n), (*len) - (result+n));
   f_memcpy((read_buf+result+n),selected, 10);
   f_memcpy(read_buf+result+n+10, temp_buf, (*len)-(result+n));
   *len=(*len)+10;`
I changed `memcpy` to my own definition of memcpy = `f_memcpy`. It now works Auto magically :).

Answer (score 1):

I think this may help, well not sure :)

```
typedef struct    //delete this so test is the struct type name// _test
{
  ...
  uint8_t txsize[5];
  uint32_t u32baudrate;
  uint8_t flowcontrol;
  ...
}test;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is quite possibly in code you have not posted.

Some `printf()` implementations use a relatively large amount of stack; you may have a stack-overflow caused by your debug method. Try removing the first `printf` call so that there is nothing between the assignment and the `httptest()` call.  If it is then not corrupted, the `printf()` itself caused the problem, and you probably need to assign a larger stack.

Otherwise an out-of-bounds access to `txsize[]` is a possibility.  Is this truly the code you are testing - with `httptest()` called directly after assignment - or have you elided the code presented?

Comment: Fixed: In the parse section of Http, where I update the packet for HTTP GET, HTTP_DEBUG_MSG("u32BaudRate = %d\n\r",test.u32BaudRate); f_memset(temp_buf, 0x00, 1024); result=pdest-read_buf; f_memcpy(temp_buf, (read_buf+result+n), (*len) - (result+n)); f_memcpy((read_buf+result+n),selected, 10); f_memcpy(read_buf+result+n+10, temp_buf, (*len)-(result+n)); *len=(*len)+10; I changed memcpy to my own definition of memcpy = f_memcpy. It now works Auto magically :).

Comment: Posting code in a comment is not particularly useful. If you think this is an answer you can post an answer to your own question or update the question.  However, I still doubt that you have truly "fixed" anything - that would suggest that `memcpy()` is broken and `f_memcpy()` is not.  Occam's Razor suggests otherwise.  More likely that f_memcpy() behaves differently (and probably incorrectly) in

Answer (score 0):

The `printf()` format specifier `%d` is used to print signed integers. However, `uint32_t` is an unsigned integer type. The usual format specifier for unsigned ints is `%u`.

Comment: I tried this did not work, the problem was structure packing, when i `PACKED` it then it worked, with no garbage data.

Comment: It may not be the solution to your issue (which, per your answer, was caused by domain-specific information that you didn't share in your question), but it is nevertheless a truth.

Comment: No, this is an uniformed suggestion - the values in question are within the range where signed and unsigned 32 bit types are compatible on this processor.

Comment: Wait, so you're saying that because in this particular case, the values being used as an example happen to have the same representation in either of these two types, that it is "uninformed" to advise the questioner that he's doing something that is, by definition, wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Packed has nothing to do with this error. Usually, an error on a printf results form stack corruption. Consider this:

```
struct wp_char{
      char wp_cval;
      short wp_font;
      short wp_psize;
}v1;

struct wp_char v2;
```

What is the difference between v1 and v2? Are they different or same? Oops....pressed the enter key by mistake.

BTW the following code works for me perfectly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;

typedef struct _test
{
    uint8_t txsize[5];
    uint32_t u32baudrate;
    uint8_t flowcontrol;
}test;

print_value(test *gtest)
{
        printf("%u\n", gtest->u32baudrate);
}

main()
{
        test gtest;

        gtest.u32baudrate = 921600;
        printf("%u\n", gtest.u32baudrate);

        print_value(&gtest);
}
```

Comment: How do I deal with stack corruption?

Comment: There is no single way to do this. I would single step through gdb and check for a particular point from where the value gets corrupted. This would narrow down the code area that needs focus.